# Where can I learn about master equation?

Tags: pr.probability, markov-chains

I am reading a paper by Dorogovstev on structure of growing complex networks with preferential linking. I need to learn master equation for this.

I need a reference for the same.

Comment: Please read the "how to ask" page.

Comment: As written, this is a very vague question.  What is the master equation?  Are you asking for a reference?  What is your background?

Comment: Start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_equation

Answer (score 2):

FYI, the referenced paper seems to be SN Dorogovtsev, JFF Mendes, AN Samukhin: "Structure of growing networks with preferential linking", Physical Revew Letters 2000.

Comment: yes thats the one